# NextJS Error When Rendering Page, After Making a Post

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, next.js

I have a Nextjs application which I connected to my NodeJS API.
I have a page with a form that i use to make POST requests to my backend API.

After making POST requests to my API, My frontend redirects me to another page.
Now here comes the problem, After redirecting me, when I press the back button, nextJS sends me to an Error page which says "An unexpected error has occurred".

I realised this bug after deploying my application, and this is a real pain.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you are achieving this

> After making POST requests to my API, My frontend redirects me to another page.

Are you using a `router.push('/submitted')` with a `handleSubmit` function?  or are you using a full page redirect?

It sounds like a full page redirect, if yes, you have two options

1. *Preferred* : Consider using the `fetch` API so you can do a POST to your backend and handle success and failures within the route. Once this is done, you can optionally push the user to a `/success` and handle any back behavior in `getserversideprops` so you can chose to hide the form OR replace the route to homepage as an example- See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerreplace

E.g:

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await fetch('<YOURBACKEND>/submit', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(<YOUR Form Fields>),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

      });

      const json = await res.json();

      if (json.success) {
        setResponse({
          type: 'success',
          message: 'Thank you for reaching out to us.'
        });

        // Assume Router is available
    router.replace('/home');
      } else {
        setResponse({
          type: 'error',
          message: json.message
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('An error occurred', e);
      setResponse({
        type: 'error',
        message: 'An error occured while submitting the form'
      });
    }
  };
// Snippet credit : https://medium.com/qualascend/add-a-static-form-to-your-nextjs-app-without-serverside-code-67e10a6ea7b8
```

2. You can simply set the cache-control to expire, causing a new fetch of the entire application
    `res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 's-maxage=60, stale-while-revalidate');`

Post more code around how you are redirecting.

Comment: Wow, your answer just worked some magic on my code, thanks. I was using Router.push. I changed it to Router.replace, and it now prevents my user from going back to the previous page, but rather it gets them 2 pages back.

Comment: Glad that helped!